# Error while Using Templates in C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates

The template i have is:

```
template <class T>
class Shape {
T val,val_new;
public:
Shape(T initval)
{
   val=initval;
}
T get()
{
   return val;
}
void set (T newval)
{
   val_new = newval;
}
void copy()
{
   val= val_new;
}
};
```

The class to use this template is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
 private:
 Shape<TwoPoint> val;
 bool incr_called, decr_called, load_called;
 TwoPoint newval;
 public:
 Rectangle(TwoPoint i)
      : val (Shape<TwoPoint> (i)) {}     
 Shape<TwoPoint> read()
 {
   return val;
 }
 void load(TwoPoint n)
 {
   load_called=1;
   newval=n;
 }
 void increment()
 {
   incr_called=1;
 }
 void decrement()
 {
   decr_called=1;
 }
 void init()
 {
   incr_called=0;
   decr_called=0;
   load_called=0;
 }
 void actions()
 { 
   if (load_called)
       val.set(new TwoPoint(newval));
   if(incr_called && !decr_called)
       val.set((new TwoPoint(val.get())).plus(1));
   if(!incr_called && decr_called)
       val.set((new TwoPoint(val.get())).plus(-1));
 }     
 };
```

TwoPoint class is defined as:

```
 class TwoPoint
 {
   int width;
   int value;
   public:
    TwoPoint()
    {
      value=0;
      width=0;
     }
     TwoPoint(int v, int w)
     {
       value=v;
       width=w;
     }
     TwoPoint(const TwoPoint& t)
     {
       value= t.value;
       width= t.width;
     }
     int getWidth()
     {
       return width;
     }
     int getValue()
     {
       return value;
     }
     TwoPoint & plus(int newval)
     {
      value+=newval;
      return *this;
     }
    };
```

But there are errors:

```
In member function 'void Rectangle::actions()':
error: request for member 'plus' in '(((TwoPoint*)operator new(8u)), (((*<anonymous>)
<unknown operator> TwoPoint<T>::get() [with T=TwoPoint]()), <anonymous>))', which is of non-class type 'TwoPoint*'
```

There is another error:

```
In member function 'void Rectangle::actions()':
error: no pattern matching function for call to 'Shape<TwoPoint>::set(TwoPoint*)'
note: candidates are: void Shape<T>:: set<T> [with T=TwoPoint]
```

There are two more errors when i am doing similar operations in actions() due to same reason. Can somebody please explain these errors and how to improve them?
**Is there any way in which i can make code more efficient?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shape::set` takes its argument by value, but you're creating a value using `new` and passing a pointer. You should avoid using `new` unless you actually need a dynamic object; in which case, you need to make sure it's deleted when you've finished with it.

In this case, you just want to pass an object by value:

```
 void actions()
 { 
   if (load_called)
       val.set(newval);
   if(incr_called && !decr_called)
       val.set(val.get().plus(1));
   if(!incr_called && decr_called)
       val.set(val.get().plus(-1));
 }
```

> Is there any way in which i can make code more efficient?

Dynamic allocation is usually less efficient than using automatic objects - fixing the error has also removed a source of inefficiency.

`Shape::set`, and the constructor, could take their arguments by reference, and `Shape::get` could return a reference, to avoid unnecessary copying; although in practice the compiler will probably avoid those copies anyway. Also, the constructor could use an initialiser list, to initialise the member(s) directly, rather than default-initialising them and the reassigning them. Code like this might be marginally more efficient in some cases:

```
Shape(T const & initval)      // pass by reference
  : val(initval)              // use initialiser list
{}
T const & get()               // return by reference
{
   return val;
}
void set (T const & newval)   // pass by reference
{
   val_new = newval;
}
```

But in general, focus on making the code correct and readable, and on choosing efficient algorithms; only worry about small inefficiencies if they prove to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` operator was the obvious culprit there. Using automatic variables solves memory leakage. Code is further improved when classes like Shape and TwoPoint can be passed as reference and not by a copied value. I admit to being a little bored and fiddling a bit with your code, even add debugging output with ostream. I cannot help you with the logic of the application though. I have no idea why certain constructs are there, so I kept most of them intact (except for val_new, because *currently* it added nothing to the code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class TwoPoint {
    int value, width;
public:
    TwoPoint() : value(0), width(0) {}
    TwoPoint(int v, int w) : value(v), width(w) {}
    TwoPoint(const TwoPoint& t) : value(t.value), width(t.width) {}
    int getWidth() { return width; }
    int getValue() { return value; }
    TwoPoint & plus(int newval) { value += newval; return *this; }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const TwoPoint& x);
};

template <class T> class Shape;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Shape<T>& x);

template <class T>
class Shape {
    T val;  // do you really need val_new?
public:
    Shape(T initval) : val(initval) {}
    T & get() { return val; }
    void set (T const & newval) { val = newval; }
    // not sure why you used and set val_new instead of val...
    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& os, const Shape<T>& x);
};

class Rectangle {
private:
    Shape<TwoPoint> val;
    bool incr_called, decr_called, load_called;
    TwoPoint newval;
public:
    Rectangle(TwoPoint i) : val(Shape<TwoPoint> (i)),
        incr_called(false), decr_called(false), load_called(false) {}     
    Shape<TwoPoint> & read() { return val; }
    void load(const TwoPoint& n) { load_called = true; newval = n; }
    void increment() { incr_called = true; }
    void decrement() { decr_called = true; }
    void init() { incr_called = decr_called = load_called = 0; }
    void actions() {
        if (load_called) {
            val.set(TwoPoint(newval));
            load_called = false;  // should the flag be reset?
        }
        if(incr_called && !decr_called) {
            val.set(val.get().plus(1));
            incr_called = false;  // should the flag be reset?
        }
        if(!incr_called && decr_called) {
            val.set(val.get().plus(-1));
            decr_called = false;  // should the flag be reset?
        }
    }     
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Rectangle& x);
};

// added for debug printouts:
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const TwoPoint& x){
    os << "TwoPoint( " << x.value << ", " << x.width << " )";
    return os;
}
template <class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Shape<T>& x){
    os << "Shape( " << x.val << " )";
    return os;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Rectangle& x){
    os << "Rectangle( " << x.val 
    << (x.load_called ? ", load_called" : "")
    << (x.incr_called ? ", incr_called" : "")
    << (x.decr_called ? ", decr_called" : "")
    << " )";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    TwoPoint tp(800, 300);
    cout << "Creating a Rectangle using " << tp << endl;
    Rectangle r(tp);
    cout << r << endl;
    r.load(TwoPoint(100, 200));
    cout << r << endl;
    r.actions();
    cout << r << endl;
    r.increment();
    cout << r << endl;
    r.actions();
    cout << r << endl;
    r.decrement();
    cout << r << endl;
    r.actions();
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output of the program:

```
Creating a Rectangle using TwoPoint( 800, 300 )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 800, 300 ) ) )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 800, 300 ) ), load_called )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 100, 200 ) ) )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 100, 200 ) ), incr_called )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 101, 200 ) ) )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 101, 200 ) ), decr_called )
Rectangle( Shape( TwoPoint( 100, 200 ) ) )
```

I hope this debug stuff proves useful when developing this app further.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
(new TwoPoint(val.get())).plus(1)
```

`new` returns a pointer-to-`TwoPoint`, so you have to use `->` instead of `.` to access member functions.

But if you did that, you'd get a memory leak in the general case.  I would suggest rethinking your design so that you don't need to dynamically allocate things.

Comment: i did not understand the memory leak part

Comment: @user: You are dynamically allocating an object, but you are never deleting that object.

Comment: @user: Start by making your code correct.  Then worry about efficiency, once you've established that it's a problem.